# TCL: sort a list of strings based on a portion of the string

Tags: list, sorting, tcl

I'm not expert in TCL, but unfortunately have to deal with it. I'm trying do do this: I have a list of strings: e.g. "test2 "test3 "test1". I want to sort the list using the number after "test". I have read all the lsort command options but I think there is no simple way, since tcl doesn't (WHY ???) consider strings as arrays like for example python does. How can I do that ? thank you all in advance.

Comment: It's usually not necessary to deal with strings as sequences of characters (and in fact Tcl considers strings to be the more fundamental datatype). When it is necessary, `split $theString {}` will give a character list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy answer is:

```
set yourlist {test2 test3 test1}
puts [lsort $yourlist]
```

But this will fail if you have numbers > 10:

```
set yourlist {test2 test3 test1 test11}
puts [lsort $yourlist]
```

So you probably need to compare this yourself:

```
proc mycompare {arg1 arg2} {
   if {[regexp {test(\d+)} $arg1 -> n1] && [regexp {test(\d+)} $arg2 -> n2]} {
       return [expr {$n1 - $n2}]
   }
   return [string compare $arg1 $arg2]
}

set yourlist {test2 test3 test1 test11}
puts [lsort -command mycompare $yourlist]
```

In fact, Tcl can consider a string as byte array, so the problem with the statement

> tcl doesn't (WHY ???) consider strings as arrays

is your definiton of "array". In Tcl we usually use lists for a sequence of values, if you want to get a list of all characters use `split $yourstring {}`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! my complain about my statement "tcl doesn't (WHY ???) consider strings as arrays" means simply that It would be easier if set a = "abcde", to simply be able to address a(2), but this is a complain of a lazy person who prefers python ;)

Comment: Well, to get the nth element from a list you use `lindex $mylist $n`, for strings you's use `string index $mystring $n`. If the Tcl API would be redesigned, then all the l* commands would be renamed to `list ...`, but there is already a `list` command, which is very important.

Answer (score 2):

The `lsort` command has an `-dictionary` option which does exactly
what you want:

```
% set lis {test1 test10 test20 test15 test3}
test1 test10 test20 test15 test3
% puts [lsort -dictionary $lis]
test1 test3 test10 test15 test20
```

Comment: thank you very much, this fits my intention, my tutorial didn't cover all the lsort options :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a Schwarzian transform approach

```
% set l {test1 test10 test20 test3}
test1 test10 test20 test3
% foreach elem $l {lappend new [list $elem [regexp -inline {\d+} $elem]]}    
% set new
{test1 1} {test10 10} {test20 20} {test3 3}
% foreach pair [lsort -index 1 -integer $new] {lappend result [lindex $pair 0]}
% puts $result
test1 test3 test10 test20
```

For Tcl 8.6

```
set result [
    lmap e [
        lsort -integer -index 1 [
            lmap e $l  {list $e [regexp -inline {\d+} $e]}
        ]
    ] {lindex $e 0}
]
```

```
test1 test3 test10 test20
```

Going *way* off-topic, this compares with the perl

```
my @l = qw/ test1 test10 test20 test3 /;
my @result = map {$_->[0]}
             sort {$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]}
             map {m/(\d+)/ and [$_, $1]}
             @l;
```

Comment: You can simplify with 8.6's `lmap`…